# Is there a better way to import variables from a Python module?

Tags: python, import, module

First, the scenario. I have a module config.py:

```
DEBUG = False    # Set to True with --debug option
```

And another module do.py that uses it:

```
from config import DEBUG

def do_something():
    if DEBUG:
        print 'Debug...'
    print 'do something'
```

And in the main.py:

```
import config
import do
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
     if len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1] == '--debug':
         config.DEBUG = True
     do.do_something()
```

Now, when I run it:

```
$ python2.7 main.py --debug
do something
```

So in `do_something()`, `DEBUG` is *False*.

What's the best way of having a configuration flag like this that:

1. works,
2. is concise, and
3. is safe?

Answer (score 1):

Addressing point 1, I can write do.py like this:

```
import config

def do_something():
    if config.DEBUG:
        print 'Debug...'
    print 'do something'
```

but now `config.DEBUG` isn't as concise (point 2).

Or I could write config.py like this:

```
class Debug(object):
    _DEBUG = False
    def __call__(self):
        return self._DEBUG
    def set(self, debug):
        self._DEBUG = debug
DEBUG = Debug()
```

But that allows for simple mistakes like this:

```
>>> import config
>>> config.DEBUG()
False
>>> from config import DEBUG
>>> DEBUG()
False
>>> DEBUG.set(True)
>>> DEBUG()
True
>>> DEBUG.set(False)
>>> DEBUG()
False
>>> if DEBUG: print 'Oops'
...
Oops
```

which violates point 3.

So is there any better solution?

Comment: You can define `__nonzero__` (named `__bool__` in Python 3) to define how `if` and `bool` treat your objects. It's up to you to decide which risk is greater: the risk of people `from`-importing flags they shouldn't, or the risk of people being confused by the magic mutating boolean-like object they got when they were expecting a boolean.

Comment: *but now config.DEBUG isn't as concise (point 2).* Why do you think so? Being explicit is a very nice as long as it's not too long, and adding the `config` namespace is pretty short.

Comment: Martin, I think you're right. Changing to `config.DEBUG` isn't so bad, and follows the Zen of Python too.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is probably the best way. In general, variables in Python belong *somewhere*, and `DEBUG` belongs in `config` more than anywhere else. If you want to import it into another module, that's fine, but you want to do it explicitly, as you're doing, not through magic.

It's worth noting that if the only thing you ever do with `DEBUG` is `if DEBUG: print <stuff>` you may be better off with a function:

```
config.debug(stuff)
```

And at that point, you may want to look at `logging` instead of reinventing a third of a wheel and hoping you don't need the other two thirds.

---

However, if you really want "works, concise, safe" without regard for pythonicity or portability, there is an alternative: the [`__builtin__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__builtin__.html) module (renamed `builtins` in Python 3.x).

In main.py:

```
import __builtin__
import do
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
     __builtin__.DEBUG = len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1] == '--debug'
     do.do_something()
```

In do.py, no need to import anything:

```
def do_something():
    if DEBUG:
        print 'Debug...'
    print 'do something'
```

Of course if you write another script, like `test.py`, that imports `do` without importing `main`, this will raise a `NameError`. But you'd get the same error from `from config import DEBUG` or `config.DEBUG` if you tried to do that before importing `main`, so it's no worse.

Why does this work? From the docs:

> **CPython implementation detail:** Most modules have the name `__builtins__` (note the 's') made available as part of their globals. The value of `__builtins__` is normally either this module or the value of this modules’s `__dict__` attribute. Since this is an implementation detail, it may not be used by alternate implementations of Python.

In particular, whenever you `import` a module or run a top-level script, unless you've done something weird with an import hook, the `exec` that executes the module's bytecode will ensure that this happens. Which means that, as long as the module doesn't shadow `DEBUG` (which is always a possibility, of course) or screw with its globals, `DEBUG` will always be found in the builtin dict. (If you `exec` any code of your own to explicitly build a `types.ModuleType`, and pass an explicit `globals` instead of inheriting it, you'll have to remember to do the same thing, but hopefully that isn't an issue.)

It happens to work in at least PyPy 2.x and 3.x and Jython 2.5 and 2.7. Beyond that? Who knows; it's not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's worth noting that

```
from config import DEBUG
```

imports the value of `DEBUG` (which is `False`) before you've set it. Later when you change it, your `do` module is still pointing to the old `False` value. If you want to make this more dynamic, you could use a function in your config:

```
# config.py
is_debug = False
def debug():
    return is_debug
```

Then in your `do.py`

```
# do.py
from config import debug
def do_something():
    if debug():
        print 'Debug...'
    print 'do something'
```